# How to localize an Eclipse RCP 4 application using Eclipse Babel?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, internationalization, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an `Eclipse RCP product` in Eclipse `e4` environment using Kepler for RCP developers on 64-bit Linux and Java 7.

I'd like to use Eclipse Babel language packages within my Eclipse product. Copying `features` and `plugins` directory into Eclipse IDE directory works without a problem. I can run my Eclipse environment in the language I want by passing `-nl` argument.

I used PDE to produce a product and applied the same step by simply copying the language package into the product's `features` and `plugins` directory. However, it did not work as I see `OK` and `Cancel` button labels still in English.

Is it correct to simply copy the files or do I have to add an extra dependency?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems solved but I'm not 100% sure. My product was based on `features`. I switched it to be a `plugins based` product. The resulting product is now displaying in local language.